# BitGO - Get MIN value from Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, foreach, min

Bitgo provides all transactions as objects and are always kept inside a big array. Inside the nested .entries we see that the first TX object has two minus values -312084680 and -4254539 from which I only need the lowest value. My code works and logs all transactions but it's only correct if the money are sent from only one address. If two minus values are present, I log 3 transactions instead of just 2.

```
var allTxs = [
   {
      "id": "e5216ffaaa2a37bcc14380db07f06c85a65bcdc4e1fcab2bd5523f0b8a11bc15",
      "normalizedHash": "0709c99097386a3c0130f3d6b002acf6a4e37978406704268fc9d308eec4c2b8",
      "date": "2016-04-17T20:07:03.700Z",
      "fee": 7440,
      "inputs": [
         {
            "previousHash": "6d043a06ade4eac5315967c463fcd65deb4ed9bff23ee3e73ff82c9cf72360e9",
            "previousOutputIndex": 1
         },
         {
            "previousHash": "b6e566cbee0f23bee7b321eda7f6159a165101e77e7f1e75bd9eb6e31540b391",
            "previousOutputIndex": 0
         }
      ],
      "outputs": [
         {
            "vout": 0,
            "account": "2N5Jr87jhTuAHab37VKWNPhoH1WUEHkVg1Q",
            "value": 312500000,
            "isMine": true,
            "chain": 0,
            "chainIndex": 0
         },
         {
            "vout": 1,
            "account": "mmRuajWq2xPYQw4gjXz8pQ2fUfJTF7fvYe",
            "value": 3831779
         }
      ],
      "entries": [
         {
            "account": "2N5Jr87jhTuAHab37VKWNPhoH1WUEHkVg1Q",
            "value": 312500000
         },
         {
            "account": "muEePZzkRWX3RnLWHxTx6r8T3MMruTgMgg",
            "value": -312084680
         },
         {
            "account": "mmRuajWq2xPYQw4gjXz8pQ2fUfJTF7fvYe",
            "value": 3831779
         },
         {
            "account": "n47gD5D3XfBG41tWKX4YHNc9gboyWU9yJg",
            "value": -4254539
         }
      ],
      "confirmations": 677,
      "pending": false,
      "instant": false,
      "blockhash": "000000000000020f526fe18af7536fa4e816694c4dec865e0d87d6b722b643d9",
      "height": 786821
   },
   {
      "id": "71fb53e7d70ce27dced2eb327ac544b8f046e66480342ba81533046f3267e6f4",
      "normalizedHash": "80116b194b58b494d85b2a831815a978ec6f0fe617cfd020880ff1ad76b2bacc",
      "date": "2016-04-17T20:06:56.474Z",
      "fee": 4480,
      "inputs": [
         {
            "previousHash": "1f4145b615f5d067160184a3e9660396f826614c3fcae9abdcb7192c615b843a",
            "previousOutputIndex": 0
         }
      ],
      "outputs": [
         {
            "vout": 0,
            "account": "2N5Jr87jhTuAHab37VKWNPhoH1WUEHkVg1Q",
            "value": 625000000,
            "isMine": true,
            "chain": 0,
            "chainIndex": 0
         },
         {
            "vout": 1,
            "account": "mpntSJWk116JF58VRDxeMMwr4gC7afVEKt",
            "value": 390110612
         }
      ],
      "entries": [
         {
            "account": "2N5Jr87jhTuAHab37VKWNPhoH1WUEHkVg1Q",
            "value": 625000000
         },
         {
            "account": "mqRsJr8szT5XTSLm3CU7i9ePa7kWnC2VWs",
            "value": -1015115092
         },
         {
            "account": "mpntSJWk116JF58VRDxeMMwr4gC7afVEKt",
            "value": 390110612
         }
      ],
      "confirmations": 689,
      "pending": false,
      "instant": false,
      "blockhash": "000000000000020f526fe18af7536fa4e816694c4dec865e0d87d6b722b643d9",
      "height": 786821
   }
];


  for (var i=0; i<allTxs.length; i++) {
    if(allTxs[i].confirmations >= 7 ) {
      var tx = allTxs[i];
      var value = 0;
      for (var entriesIndex = 0; entriesIndex < tx.entries.length; ++entriesIndex) {
        if (tx.entries[entriesIndex].account === wallet.id()) {
          value += tx.entries[entriesIndex].value;
        }
      }
      for ( var receivedFrom = 0; receivedFrom < tx.entries.length; ++receivedFrom ){
          if (tx.entries[receivedFrom].value < 0){
                var verb = (value > 0) ? 'Received' : 'Sent';
                  console.log(tx.entries[receivedFrom].account + ' : ' + verb + ' ' + (value / 1e8).toFixed(8));

        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This is where the magic happens:

```
if (tx.entries[receivedFrom].value < 0){
                  // both values are less than 0
```

Hoping that someone finds this easy and lends a helping hand !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few changes to improve the readability of your code, changing the name of the variables, and using forEach instead of the traditional for loop. Also created an object called minEntry which stores the entry with the lowest value. Hope this helped you

```
   var allTransactions = [
   {
      "id": "e5216ffaaa2a37bcc14380db07f06c85a65bcdc4e1fcab2bd5523f0b8a11bc15",
      "normalizedHash": "0709c99097386a3c0130f3d6b002acf6a4e37978406704268fc9d308eec4c2b8",
      "date": "2016-04-17T20:07:03.700Z",
      "fee": 7440,
      "inputs": [
         {
            "previousHash": "6d043a06ade4eac5315967c463fcd65deb4ed9bff23ee3e73ff82c9cf72360e9",
            "previousOutputIndex": 1
         },
         {
            "previousHash": "b6e566cbee0f23bee7b321eda7f6159a165101e77e7f1e75bd9eb6e31540b391",
            "previousOutputIndex": 0
         }
      ],
      "outputs": [
         {
            "vout": 0,
            "account": "2N5Jr87jhTuAHab37VKWNPhoH1WUEHkVg1Q",
            "value": 312500000,
            "isMine": true,
            "chain": 0,
            "chainIndex": 0
         },
         {
            "vout": 1,
            "account": "mmRuajWq2xPYQw4gjXz8pQ2fUfJTF7fvYe",
            "value": 3831779
         }
      ],
      "entries": [
         {
            "account": "2N5Jr87jhTuAHab37VKWNPhoH1WUEHkVg1Q",
            "value": 312500000
         },
         {
            "account": "muEePZzkRWX3RnLWHxTx6r8T3MMruTgMgg",
            "value": -312084680
         },
         {
            "account": "mmRuajWq2xPYQw4gjXz8pQ2fUfJTF7fvYe",
            "value": 3831779
         },
         {
            "account": "n47gD5D3XfBG41tWKX4YHNc9gboyWU9yJg",
            "value": -4254539
         }
      ],
      "confirmations": 677,
      "pending": false,
      "instant": false,
      "blockhash": "000000000000020f526fe18af7536fa4e816694c4dec865e0d87d6b722b643d9",
      "height": 786821
   },
   {
      "id": "71fb53e7d70ce27dced2eb327ac544b8f046e66480342ba81533046f3267e6f4",
      "normalizedHash": "80116b194b58b494d85b2a831815a978ec6f0fe617cfd020880ff1ad76b2bacc",
      "date": "2016-04-17T20:06:56.474Z",
      "fee": 4480,
      "inputs": [
         {
            "previousHash": "1f4145b615f5d067160184a3e9660396f826614c3fcae9abdcb7192c615b843a",
            "previousOutputIndex": 0
         }
      ],
      "outputs": [
         {
            "vout": 0,
            "account": "2N5Jr87jhTuAHab37VKWNPhoH1WUEHkVg1Q",
            "value": 625000000,
            "isMine": true,
            "chain": 0,
            "chainIndex": 0
         },
         {
            "vout": 1,
            "account": "mpntSJWk116JF58VRDxeMMwr4gC7afVEKt",
            "value": 390110612
         }
      ],
      "entries": [
         {
            "account": "2N5Jr87jhTuAHab37VKWNPhoH1WUEHkVg1Q",
            "value": 625000000
         },
         {
            "account": "mqRsJr8szT5XTSLm3CU7i9ePa7kWnC2VWs",
            "value": -1015115092
         },
         {
            "account": "mpntSJWk116JF58VRDxeMMwr4gC7afVEKt",
            "value": 390110612
         }
      ],
      "confirmations": 689,
      "pending": false,
      "instant": false,
      "blockhash": "000000000000020f526fe18af7536fa4e816694c4dec865e0d87d6b722b643d9",
      "height": 786821
   }
];

  allTransactions.forEach(function (transaction){    
      var value = 0;
      var minEntry = { value : 0 };
      transaction.entries.forEach(function (entry) {
         //if (entry.account === wallet.id()) {
          value += entry.value;
         //}
      });
      var verb = (value > 0) ? 'Received' : 'Sent';
      transaction.entries.forEach(function (entry) {
          if (entry.value < minEntry.value){
            minEntry = entry;
         }
      });
      if(minEntry.value){
        console.log(minEntry.account + ' : ' + verb + ' ' + (value / 1e8).toFixed(8));
      }
  });
```

Comment: Oh sorry, try transaction.entries.forEach

Comment: changed minValue to minEntry, was getting minValue is undefined . No errors after that but console.log(minEntry.account + ' : ' + verb + ' ' + (value / 1e8).toFixed(8)); does not get called.

Comment: I edited the code, try again. In the code that you provided the object wallet does not exist.

Comment: No problem :) If you have any other question leave it in the comments or send me a PM, it's fun to help